# Using Take() with Anonymous type (DB2 Provider)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, db2, anonymous-types

I am using a DB2 provider to hit a database on an AiX Server. Here is the LINQ statement I am using to that returns an anonymous type.

```
var docs = (from a in WIP
            where (!dtFrom.HasValue && !dtTo.HasValue) || (a.QBE_DT.Value >= dtFrom.Value && a.QBE_DT.Value <= dtTo.Value) && a.STATUSCODE != "X" && a.KEY1 != "CABS" && a.KEY1 != "BPI"
            group a by new
            {
                a.BATCH_ID,
                a.POLICY_NUM,
                a.QBE_DT
            } into grp
            select new
            {
                BatchId = grp.Key.BATCH_ID.Trim(),
                BatchGroup = grp
            }).ToList();
```

The return from this is causing the Provider to timeout, throwing a Process has been canceled due to an interrupt error. My thought is if I "Take" a subset of the recordset, this issue will go away. The issue I have, is I cannot simply add a `Take(100)` before the `ToList()`, because it throws:

```
SQL0418N A statement contains a use of an untyped parameter marker, the DEFAULT keyword, or a null value that is not valid. SQLSTATE=42610
```

I wish I was able to see the SQL generated to make sure it is the right syntax, but I don't know how to in this situation. Is there an elegant way to get the first X Elements from above LINQ statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround for this was to do the grouping and filtering in memory and getting a larger amount of data back from the source

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is really arising from your use of anonymous types, you could just create a named type instead.

```
public class BatchKey
{
    public int BatchId {get;set;}
    ...
}
...
        group a by new BatchKey
        {
            BatchId = a.BATCH_ID,
            ...
```

However, that error message is sort of cryptic, and I'm not sure this has anything to do with anonymous types. I'd suggest paring your query down piece by piece until you have a bare minimum that reproduces the error. That way you'll be far more certain what is causing the issue.

You may want to consider adding an `OrderBy` before your `Take`, since some providers require that a set of data be ordered in order to perform a `Take`. You might also want to evaluate what you can outside of your query:

```
IQueryable<WIP> wips = WIP.Where(a => a.STATUSCODE != "X" && a.KEY1 != "CABS" && a.KEY1 != "BPI");
if (dtFrom.HasValue) {
   wips = docs.Where(a => a.QBE_DT.Value >= dtFrom.Value);
}
if (dtTo.HasValue) {
   wips = docs.Where(a => a.QBE_DT.Value <= dtTo.Value);
}
var docs = from a in wips
           group a by ...
```

I believe you should be able to set up LINQPad to use your DB2 provider, and see the SQL statements that are getting produced. (But this error looks like it's happening before an SQL statement is generated).

Comment: It definently is the group by then the take(). I am able to take the group by out, store the result in memory, then group by. I could jsut do this, but it is not as elegant. Thoughts?

Comment: @IsaacLevin: What happens if you create a named class to represent the objects you're grouping by, and use that instead of an anonymous type?

Comment: @StriplingWarrier, can you give me an example, I am not following.

Comment: @IsaacLevin: I updated the answer with a brief code sample to give you an idea.

Comment: I created the type and got the same SQL error, so it may be an issue with the provider. I have not been able to see the SQL generated using LinqPad, just the object context because I use EF. It looks like I would have to write a driver for LinqPad to get DB2 to work.

Comment: @IsaacLevin: It's definitely an issue with the LINQ provider, and I'd suggest logging a bug report with them. I was just hoping you'd be able to find some other way to structure the query as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably this part and the other references to the objects not in the query.

```
(!dtFrom.HasValue && !dtTo.HasValue)
```

Take that out and see if it works.